# How to remove list items which are not numbers?

Tags: python

I have an object 'a' I want to convert it to a list such that it does not have any characters but numbers. Though, similar questions talk about list comprehensions but i was looking for a function method which will help me collect the numbers.

```
>>> a
['(', '0', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '3', ',', ' ', '4', ',', ' ', '5', ',', ' ', '6', ',', ' ', '7', ',', ' ', '8', ',', ' ', '9', ')']
```

Now, I was thinking about approaching this problem in two parts. 
First, i wanted to remove all ',' and ' '(blank spaces).

For this I coded :

```
>>> for x in a :
    if x == ',' or x == ' ':
        del x
```

This does not change the list at all.

Also, is there any way in which I can iterate through each object and check if it is a number and if it is not delete it. I think this would be much simpler.

Moreover, if there is a better way to resolve this, please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: The `del` statement can't delete things that a variable is pointing to since it only deletes the first level reference. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement "Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace" So all you're doing with `del x` is remove the binding for `x` - and not the thing that `x` is pointing to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a general rule you should avoid modifying an iterable while iterating over it ([see why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list)), although in this case your code is not deleting any elements as @rdas points out. Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead:

```
[i for i in l if i.isnumeric()]
# ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Comment: This was so simple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to accept :), see the link I shared (green tick under the voting options) @VinamraBali

Comment: Make sure `isnumeric` test is consistent with your notion of a 'number' string. E.g. these are NOT numeric: "+1", "-1", "0.0".